# Parse multiple json files in one activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to use data factory to regularly download 500000 json files from a web API and store them in a blob storage container. Then I need to parse the json files to extract some values from each file and store these values together with an ID (part of filename) in a database. I can do this using a ForEach activity and run a custom activity for each file, but this is very slow, so I would prefer some batch activity which could run the same parsing code on each file. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your source json files have same schema, you can leverage the Copy Activity which can parse those files in a single run. But if possible, I would suggest to split those files into different sub folder (e.g. 1000 files per folder), so that each copy run needs less time and ease the management.

Refer to this doc for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview

Comment: I thought about the Copy Activity, but I don't think it will work in my case:
1. The ID is part of the filename, and I don't think the Copy Activity can extract the filename.
2. The json files have the same schema, but I need to have some logic to determine which fields to extract.